# Cakephp advanced routing and pagination

Tags: php, routes, pagination, seo, cakephp-2.0

For SEO purpose, I have to put all form data into an URL. Here's the routing :

```
Router::connect('/liste-voitures/:marque/:modele/:categorie/:energie',
                array(
                    'controller' => 'vehicules',
                    'action' => 'index',
                ),
                array(
                    'pass' => array(
                                  'marque',
                                  'modele',
                                  'categorie',
                                  'energie'
                              )
                )
);
```

So in my index action I've built an array with the values and pass it to the redirect function to match with the route :

```
$urlbuilding = array(
    'action' => 'index',
    'marque' => 'volvo-3', 
    'modele' => 'C30-2',
    'categorie' => 'citadine',
    'energie' => 'diesel'
);
$this->redirect($urlbuilding);
```

This is working fine as I get to the URL :

```
/liste-voitures/volvo-3/C30-2/citadine/diesel/
```

Except for the pagination. The page numbers are pointing to the URL :

```
/vehicules/index/volvo-3/C30-2/citadine/diesel/page:2/sort:Vehicule.recommande/direction:desc
```

and it should be

```
/liste-voitures/volvo-3/C30-2/citadine/diesel/page:2/sort:Vehicule.recommande/direction:desc
```

I tried to change the url by setting Pagination options :

```
$this->Paginator->options = array(
             'url' => array(
            'action' => 'index',
            'marque' => $this->request->params['marque'],
            'modele' => $this->request->params['modele'],
            'categorie' => $this->request->params['categorie'],
            'energie' => $this->request->params['energie']
                     )
);
```

But it didn't work better.

I then tried to add a route with a wildcard :

```
Router::connect('/liste-voitures/:marque/:modele/:categorie/:energie/*',
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'vehicules',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'pass' => array(
                                'marque',
                                'modele',
                                'categorie',
                                'energie',
                                'page',
                                'sort',
                                'direction'
                        )
                    )
);
```

But It did'nt work. And I'm not yet trying to get the page, sort and direction values prettier as in

```
/liste-voitures/volvo-3/C30-2/citadine/diesel/2/Vehicule.recommande/desc
```

... but that would be my next step ;)

Do anyone would mind telling me if I'm doing something wrong ? It's been days since I last had the feeling to move forward with this project. I would be very grateful if someone could drive me on the right way ! :)

Answer (score 0):

SEO urls and Cakephp pagination urls are two different sides of a coin!

For urls use your own logic and pass parameters to pagination settings,  in your views you can create seo friendly urls and will be able to use paginator component of cakephp.

```
Router::connect('/liste-voitures/:marque/:modele/:categorie/:energie/:page/:sort/:direction',
                    array(
                        'controller' => 'vehicules',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'pass' => array(
                                'marque',
                                'modele',
                                'categorie',
                                'energie',
                                'page',
                                'sort',
                                'direction'
                        )
                    )
);
```

This should be your routing and use your own logic too create pagination urls, do not use paginate helper.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. But I don't think I understood it ... can you be more specific ?

What do you mean by "For urls use your own logic and pass parameters to pagination settings" ?